# This returns a Stack Empty Exception for me when I move items from stack 1 to 2. Can you please help me figure out what is wrong?

Tags: java, queue, stack

```
private MyStack stack1 = new MyStack();
private MyStack stack2 = new MyStack();

    public int dequeue() {
            int x = 0;
            while(!stack1.isEmpty()) {
                stack2.push(stack1.pop());
            }
            return x;
        }
```

The program is to move items from stack 1 to 2. The problem is that it throws a StackEmptyException when I push from stack 1 to 2. I tried to push normal integers to both stacks and it seemed fine.

```
public class MyStack {
    static final int MAX = 100;
    private int[] array = new int[MAX];
    private int top;
    
    public MyStack(){
        top = -1;
    }
    
    boolean isEmpty() {
        return (top < 0);
    }
    
    public void setArraySize(int x) {
        array = new int[x];
    }
    
    public int peek(){ // displays the number on top of stack
        return array[top];
    }
    
    public void push(int x) { // puts a number on top of stack
        if(top>=array.length-1) {
            System.out.println("StackFullException");
        }
        array[++top] = x;
    }
    
    public int pop() { // removes the number that is on top of stack
        if(top<array.length) {
            System.out.println("StackEmptyException");
        }
        int x = array[top--];
        return x;
    }
}
```

This is my stack declaration that is based from an array.

Comment: Can you post the declaration of stack1 and stack2?  If they are your own implementations their code as well might be needed.

Comment: This is my first time asking in Stack I will momentarily

Comment: I tried this code with the variables defined as `Deque<Integer> stack1 = new LinkedList<>();` and `stack2` defined similarly, using the types from `java.util.*` and pushing a few values onto `stack1` before calling it, and it worked just fine.

Comment: It worked just fine for me as well. Can you please declaration of stack1 and 2..?

Comment: I updated the post!

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to Java. They are both objects from the MyStack class.

Comment: Yes. the condition in `pop` is wrong. It always considers the stack to be empty. Replace it with `if (isEmpty())` and all should be well. @user16320675 if you post that as an answer I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: I  just noticed that just now and I can't believe it took me a couple of days to see it. Thanks man!

Comment: "I can't believe it took me a couple of days to see it" this is exact reason why knowledge about how to use debugger is essential for programmer (and it is not very hard to learn, just pick some IDE and search for its debugging tutorials).

Answer (score 2):

```
public int pop() { // removes the number that is on top of stack
    if(top<0) {
        System.out.println("StackEmptyException");
    }
    int x = array[top--];
    return x;
}
```

I mistakenly set my if statement to throw a StackEmptyExeception if top < the array.